# Was Erza's nickname 'Titania' inspired by Shakespeare?

Tags: fairy-tail

I read on [Fanpop](http://www.fanpop.com/clubs/fairy-tail/answers/show/184159/can-anyone-tell-why-ezra-called-titania) that the name Titania comes from a Shakespearean play called ***A Midsummer Night's Dream***.

In this play, it happens to be that Titania is queen of fairies. Did the creators of *Fairy Tail* happen to get inspiration from Shakespeare's plays and was that how Erza got the nickname 'Titania'? Also did they use this play as an inspiration for the name of the anime *Fairy Tail*?

Note: I came across this when I was trying to find out why Erza had the nickname Titania? I did a Google search but didn't find out any solid answers besides...

> She's the strongest mage in the guild, and that's how she earned the nickname Titania.

To sum it up, I am not asking how she got the nickname in the show, but how the producers came up with the nickname. What was their inspiration for the nickname Titania.

Please refrain from saying:

1. She got her nickname from being the strongest in the guild
2. The producers came up with that nickname because she is strong

Comment: It seems safe to say that 'Titania' is a name taken from _A Midsummer Night's Dream_, but beyond that I can't answer your question, having only watched around 4 episodes of Fairy Tail.

Comment: I only just started watching Fairy Tail around last week. Still fairly new to Fairy Tail.

Comment: I read everything in Fairy Tail, but it seems there's no other explanation except she got her nickname from being the strongest in the guild

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Shakespeare's *A Midsummer Night's Dream*, Titania is the Queen of the fairies.

Since Erza is widely known as the strongest female mage of *Fairy Tail*, she has been given the nickname Titania.